# JQuery clone and change element ID

Tags: php, jquery

I want to clone of this TR of a perticular table and changed its id accordinlgly.

```
<tr id="tr">
    <td class="row form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="first">  
    </td>
    <td class="row form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="second">
    </td>
    <td class="row form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="third">
    </td>
    <td class="row form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="forth">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <a href="#" disabled="disabled">
           <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have tried so far.

```
var cloneCount = 1;
$("#tr").clone().attr('id', 'id'+ cloneCount++).insertAfter("#tr");
```

but this is not liking to me.
**Update :**
It generate/update id of TR but really i don't want this, actually i wanted to do is changed id's like first0,second0,third0,forth0 and first1,second1,third1,forth1 and so on.
hope you understand all.

Comment: *but this is not liking to me.* -Not sure what this means, but Seems to be working. http://jsfiddle.net/pts6ss72/ :  Try `$("#tr").clone().attr('id', $("#tr")[0].id+ cloneCount++)` if you need ID as `tr1,tr2...`

Comment: Works for me too.... http://jsfiddle.net/jdfxv0q6/

Comment: i have updated my question/ please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/jdfxv0q6/1/

Here, I added a new class to the html (clonableDiv), and range goes first1, first2... if you want to start from first0, change to

```
.size-2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tr").clone().attr('id', 'id'+ cloneCount++).insertAfter("#tr");
```

Above line will change only clone `tr`  id.

You need to do the following to change `input` element id

```
$("#tr").clone().find('input').attr('id', function( i, val ){
     return val + cloneCount;
});
```